# Unit test tasks run in parallel using QThreadPool

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, parallel-processing, qthread

I am using [`QThreadPool`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthreadpool.html) to run tasks in my application in parallel. The tasks take the thread pool as an argument, so they can start new tasks. How can I write unit tests for the tasks and assert that the correct next tasks are started?

```cpp
class MyTask: public QRunnable {
public:
    virtual void run() {
        m_threadPool.start(/*another task*/);
        m_threadPool.start(/*a third task*/);
    }
private:
    QThreadPool &m_threadPool;
};
```

I would like to test `MyTask`:

```cpp
QThreadPool threadPool;
threadPool.start(new MyTask(threadPool));
threadPool.waitForDone();

// Assert that another task and a third task is started.
```

I tried extending `QThreadPool` and log started tasks:

```cpp
class MyThreadPool : public QThreadPool {
public:
    virtual void start(QRunnable *runnable, int priority = 0) {
        m_Queue.enqueue(runnable);
        // The task is not started, so I can manually start each task and test the outcome.
    }
    QQueue<QRunnable *> queue() const { return m_queue; }
private:
    QQueue<QRunnable *> m_queue;
};


MyThreadPool threadPool;
threadPool.start(new MyTask(threadPool));
threadPool.waitForDone();

QQueue<QRunnable *> Queue({ /*another task and a third task*/ });
Assert::IsEquavalent(threadPool.queue(), Queue);
```

But this does not work, since `QThreadPool::start()` is not virtual. What is the best approach for writing my test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding the problems about the fact that `QThreadPool::start()` is not a virtual function, you can do something like this:

Instead of overriding a function, you can use your subclass in MyTask and use a different function that will call run. Something like this:

```
class MyThreadPool : public QThreadPool {
public:
    void enqueue_and_run(QRunnable *runnable, int priority = 0) {
        m_Queue.enqueue(runnable);
        QThreadPool::start(runnable, priority);
    }

    const QQueue<QRunnable *>& queue() const { 
         return m_queue; 
    }
private:
    QQueue<QRunnable *> m_queue;
};

class MyTask: public QRunnable {
public:
    virtual void run() {
        m_threadPool.enqueue_and_run(/*another task*/);
        m_threadPool.enqueue_and_run(/*a third task*/);
    }
private:
    MyThreadPool &m_threadPool;
};
```

THen run the same test code:

```
MyThreadPool threadPool;
threadPool.enqueue_and_run(new MyTask(threadPool));
threadPool.waitForDone();

QQueue<QRunnable *> Queue({ /*another task and a third task*/ });
Assert::IsEquavalent(threadPool.queue(), Queue);
```

It is not the most elegant way to do so, but it makes clear your intentions.

As an alternative, if you want to keep a common interface, you can use a basic function overloading:

```
template <class TPool>
void start(TPool* pool, QRunnable *runnable, int priority = 0) {
    pool->start(runnable, priority);
}

void start(MyThreadPool* pool, QRunnable *runnable, int priority = 0) {
    pool->enqueue_and_run(pool, runnable, priority);
}
```

Then your test code will work pretty similar to the original one:

```
MyThreadPool threadPool;
start(threadPool, new MyTask(threadPool));
threadPool.waitForDone();
// ... rest of the code
```

Comment: This will reduce performance, since `MyTask` is intended to be used in production.

Comment: Why do you think it will reduce performance? The original implementation with polymorphism also needs to call the base class implementation (if it was possible).